# Create a FieldExpression instead of ConstantExpression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, roslyn

This is a little bit tricky to explain so I start with an example.

```cs
     class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lst = new List<Test>();
            var value = "John";
            var exp1 = lst.AsQueryable().Where(l => l.Name == "John").Expression as MethodCallExpression;
            var exp2 = lst.AsQueryable().Where(l => l.Name == value).Expression as MethodCallExpression;

            Console.WriteLine(exp1.Arguments.Last().ToString()); // l => (l.name == "John")
            Console.WriteLine(exp2.Arguments.Last().ToString()); // l => (l.name == value(test1.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).value)
        }
    }
    class Test
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

the name value (John) is a `ConstantExpression` in the `exp1` example that we can create it using `Expression.Constant()` function but I need to somehow create the second expression `(exp2)`, the value is not simply a Constant and has a reference to a local variable. The **value** is a `FieldExpression` In `exp2` example.

The main goal is to create `exp2` using Roslyn APIs and expressions, I don't know how should I pass the value exactly to achieve that.

To create the `exp1` we can do something like this:

```cs
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test), "l");
    var member = Expression.PropertyOrField( parameter , "Name");
    var valueExp = Expression.Constant(value);
    var exp1 = Expression.Equal(member, valueExp);
```

How can I create `exp2` !?

Comment: What's your use case for this? What're you trying to do with that?

Comment: @Timo: check this out: https://github.com/alirezanet/Gridify/issues/24 
EntityFramework SQL providers have a different behavior when we use `ConstantExpression` (last two comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it helps to use a decompiler to see how C# implements this expression;

```cs
string value = "Foo";
Expression<Func<string,bool>> test = f => f == value;
```

[Becomes](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAExAagD4AEBMBGAsAKHQAYACdbAOgBlYBHCgUQA8AHAJwFMBnLqAexhcA3AXQBmMphIBhEgG8CJJWQnoALCQCyACgCU8xcqPlSANwgAbAK4cSAXhIAiAGJ8+jkfiNHm7brwEAHnQAVmDsIjhgNwsAPliSABduRPsSADN7BMy7B3NrDk8jAF8CYqA===);

```cs
    private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
    {
        public string value;
    }

    public void M()
    {
        <>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = new <>c__DisplayClass0_0();
        <>c__DisplayClass0_.value = "Foo";
        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "f");
        BinaryExpression body = Expression.Equal(parameterExpression, Expression.Field(Expression.Constant(<>c__DisplayClass0_, typeof(<>c__DisplayClass0_0)), FieldInfo.GetFieldFromHandle((RuntimeFieldHandle)/*OpCode not supported: LdMemberToken*/)));
        ParameterExpression[] array = new ParameterExpression[1];
        array[0] = parameterExpression;
        Expression<Func<string, bool>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(body, array);
    }
```

If you replaced the `FieldInfo.GetFieldFromHandle((RuntimeFieldHandle)/*OpCode not supported: LdMemberToken*/)` with a `FieldInfo` that you obtained via reflection, you should have something that compiles.

You can see that C# has generated a new class, so that the local variable can be stored there instead of on the stack.

The instance of this class is passed into the expression as a constant, then the field of that class is accessed.

I also find it useful to let C# create a template expression, then define an `ExpressionVisitor` to swap some small part of that expression with something else.

For example you could write an `ExpressionVisitor` which swaps every instance of parameter `f` in the `Body` of the above expression, with the `Body` of `l => l.Name` to create a new lambda. Without needing to worry about exactly how the value parameter is supplied.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy nice catch. this is a performance-optimizing change for me so the question is how can I achieve this without having reflection overheads!

Comment: Due to the constant class reference, you'll need to rebuild most of the expression on every call. Though you can cache reflection metadata statically. I wouldn't worry too much about the cost of building the expression tree itself. If you were calling `.Where(...)` "normally" the expression tree is built every time anyway.